# Many-to-one post-hoc comparisons after Friedman test

Tags: repeated-measures, nonparametric, post-hoc, friedman-test

Is there any established technique (something like the Dunnet test) for performing many-to-one *post-hoc* comparisons after the Friedman rank test for repeated measures?

I would be also very grateful for pointing me to any R implementations of such a technique if there are any.

EDIT.
By many-to-one *post-hoc* comparison I of course mean for instance comparing all measurements to a baseline.